# Change referral link

Tags: javascript, html

I have question. Is there any way for html or javascript?

I have `adf.ly` referral link(example): `adf.ly/12345 + link`.

To download my source download file1 i input link as: `adf.ly/12345/https://example.com/downloadfile1`

For file2 link i input `adf.ly/12345/https://example.com/downloadfile2`

.. and so on for many links.
But one day I need to change my referral link from adf.ly/12345 to adf.ly/6789
So i need to change above link one by one:

`adf.ly/6789/https://example.com/downloadfile1`

`adf.ly/6789/https://example.com/downloadfile2`

.. and so on.

My question, is there any way to auto change any link start from `adf.ly/12345+url` to `adf.ly/6789+link`, using html or JavaScript?

I try to search the topic, but I'm just beginner. I cant find any or maybe wrong search.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suppose you are using two input tags, first to get input for the initial url and in the next input field insert the new url, when clicking the button, it will replace the existing url with the new one everywhere.

```js
function replaceUrl () {
    
    let initial = document.getElementById("initial").value;
    let replace = document.getElementById("replace").value;
    let url = ['shorte.st/abc123/https://example.com/downloadfile2', 'adf.ly/12345/https://example.com/downloadfile2']
    url = url.map((u) => u.includes(initial) ? u.replace(initial, replace) : u)
    console.log(url)
}
```

```html
Enter first part <input type="text" id="initial"/>
Enter second part <input type="text" id="replace"/>
<input type="button" value="Change" onclick="replaceUrl()">
```

Comment: How about if I change `adf.ly/12345/https://example.com/downloadfile1` to `shorte.st/abc123/https://example.com/downloadfile1` ?
What Code do I need to enter?

Comment: Updated answer have a look

Comment: Is there any way to replace `adf.ly/12345` with any new update link?

Comment: You can provide the adf.ly and 12345 separately in the two different text input.

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you. I'm new and can't upvote yet.

Comment: Look likes I have to input every link `${link}/${num}/https://example.com/downloadfile2` all links? For downloadfile3, 4, 5 etc. Can I just set once and whenever user click on any link start `adf.ly/12345/...`, it will change automatically?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer as per your issue.